# Helpful Sherlock Fragment ListView examples or advice

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-viewpager, actionbarsherlock

I'm looking for some ideas on how to do a simple listview with images while inside a SherlockFragment class; Which is then loaded into a ViewPager fragment. I've tried several examples listed below, each one I cannot get to successfully work. I'm not asking for someone to do it for me, I'm looking for advice on how to build one from someones experience to direct me for resources.

Examples i have tried

[android fragment example](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/08/android-fragment-example.html)
[android sdk fragments](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_fragments/)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the listview with images is no problem.

To show fragments in a viewpager you should work with the support-library and go like this:

1. you create a layout with a viewpager:

   ```
   <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
       android:id="@+id/view_pager"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
   ```
2. create a fragment that inflates your layout in 1., your on onCreateView Method should conatin the following lines:

   ```
   View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_pager_layout, parent, false);
   MyFragmentAdapter mMyPagerAdapter = 
           new MyFragmentAdapter (getChildFragmentManager());
   // ... set data to pager
   mMyPagerAdapter.setCountOfFragments(mCountOfFragments);

   mViewPager = (ViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
   mViewPager.setAdapter(mMyPagerAdapter);
   ```

3.create a class that extends from FragmentStatePagerAdapter. This should look like this:

```
public class MyFragmentAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter{

public MyFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // create here you listfragment that should be shown in your viewPager
    Fragment fragment = new ...;

    // you also can set data to this listFragment
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);

    return fragment;
}

    @Override
public int getCount() {
    return mCountOfFragments;
}
}
```

These Links were helpfull for me:

http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html

And also the sample of effectivenavigation (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/d80ee02/samples/training/EffectiveNavigation) is really helpful.